# How to center navbar items? (responsively)

Tags: html, css, navbar, responsive

Tried many things but nothing workd. Hope you guys can help me out.
My navbar looks like this:

```css
    .navbar-nav{
     float: left;
     
    }
    
    .navbar img{
     width: 35px;
    }
    
    #navi{
     position: fixed;
     width: 100%;
      z-index:1;
    }
    
    .navbar a{
     font-size: 25px;
     
    }
    
    .navbar{
     background-color: #000000;
    }
    
    .halter{
     padding: 5px;
    }
    
    .navbar-toggler{
      
    }
    
    .navbar-brand{
     margin-left: 12px;
     font-family: Gotham, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial," sans-serif";
    }
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar navbar-light" style="background-color: #FFFFFF"> 
      <img src="WildfireGraphic1.png" class="rounded float-left" alt="icon1"> 
       <a data-scrol class="navbar-brand" href="#text1"> 
       <span class="prwaldbrand">Projekt&nbsp; <span class="secondword">Waldbrand</span></span>
       </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"> 
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span> </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a> </li>
            <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Film</a> </li>
            <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Info</a> </li>
            <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Über uns</a> </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
```

I want the *li* elements in my *ul* to be responsively centered in the middle of the navbar. Coudn't figure out the solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi - just following up. Was your question answered satisfactorily? If there is more we can help with, please add a comment below one of the answers, or edit your question to clarify what else you need help with. Otherwise, it would be great if you could choose a "best answer" *(by clicking the checkmark beside the answer)* to close out the question. ***Also note that you can upvote instead of*** **(or in addition to)** ***the checkmark, to reward answers that were also helpful.***

Comment: Hi Hasso - following up again. Could we trouble you to select a best answer -- or provide you own and select that -- to close out the question? That would help us out. *Many Thanks*

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this css:

```
#navbarNav{justify-content:center;}
```

How would you figure that out for yourself?

1. Understand that bootstrap provides all classes and css for you, but it is designed ***to be overridden where needed***
2. In Chrome browser:

   a. Right-click on the area that doesn't look right.

   b. Choose INSPECT from the pop-up context menu

   c. Maximize the DevTools panel. On the left side is the HTML that makes up the page; on the right side is the CSS for the element currently highlighted on the left side. Experiment away!

```js
/*
  You need this at FULL SCREEN to see the effect (top right link)
  The fix is: .navbar-nav{justify-content:center;}
*/
```

```css
.navbar-nav{}
.navbar img{width:35px;}
#navi{position:fixed;width:100%;z-index:1;}
.navbar a{font-size:25px;}
.navbar{background-color:#000000;}
.halter{padding:5px;}
.navbar-toggler{}
.navbar-brand{margin-left:12px;font-family:Gotham, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial," sans-serif";}

/* ADD THIS */
#navbarNav{justify-content:center;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar navbar-light" style="background-color: #FFFFFF"> 
      <img src="WildfireGraphic1.png" class="rounded float-left" alt="icon1"> 
       <a data-scrol class="navbar-brand" href="#text1"> 
       <span class="prwaldbrand">Projekt&nbsp; <span class="secondword">Waldbrand</span></span>
       </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"> 
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span> </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a> </li>
            <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Film</a> </li>
            <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Info</a> </li>
            <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Über uns</a> </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to apply the css in the **ul** and in the **li**

```
.navbar-nav{
    float: left;
}
.navbar-nav ul {
    float: left;
}
.navbar-nav ul li{
    float: left;
}
```